# Doxygen LaTeX / PDF links point to page 1

Tags: pdf, latex, doxygen

I am using Doxygen to create a product manual, and I ran into this issue.

Some links in the outputted PDF (created from LaTeX) are broken; they point to the first page of the document.

[image: Failure to link within PDF]

The accompanying HTML output does not suffer from this issue; links work just fine, as shown below:

[image]

The Doxygen code for this page:

```
/** 
    @mainpage [product] Developer's Guide

    Blah blah blah.

    This manual is divided into the following sections:
    - @subpage intro
    - @subpage [etc]
 */
```

#### Further notes:

- I tried @ref instead of @subpage. No difference.
- Some other references in the PDF are broken as well (automatic file references in some sections), but many work fine.

Here's the LaTeX intermediate for this page:

```
This manual is divided into the following section\-:
\begin{DoxyItemize}
\item \hyperlink{intro}{Product Introduction}
[etc]
```

### Edit: Manual Solution Found

- Open refman.tex from the LaTeX output directory
- Change the entry `\hypertarget{d1/dfb/intro}{}` to `\hypertarget{intro}{}`
- Repeat for other pages
- Run the LaTeX to PDF tool

This is obviously not a viable solution for automated processes though, so this question is definitely still open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the answer provided by @aaronncfca. The problem is caused by the not proper handling of paths in case CREATE_SUBDIRS is set to YES. 
A, proposed,patch has been created for this problem and pushed (pull request 328) to github

Answer (score 0):

Valid workaround found: Disable CREATE_SUBDIRS in the Doxygen configuration (Expert tab, Project topic in doxywizard).

The issue (as shown in the manual solution in my question) is that Doxygen puts the path in the hypertarget thing, where only the symbol is needed. By eliminating the path entirely, disabling sub-directories fixes the issue.